# Can you make global variables available in every screen?

Tags: python, kivy, global-variables

I would like to use global variables that once calculated with a method on the Input Screen, can be used to display information on the display screen but also be imported to the Display Screen to finish other calculations that will displayed on the screen.

My current global variables will be created on the Input Screen calculations() and Display Screen display fill. Also, the global variables will be used in an on_enter function in more calculations.

I am also having an issue getting the camera to capture the image. It displays on the screen but I dont get a saved picture.
main.py

```
import kivy
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp, sp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

Builder.load_file('tipBot.kv')
Builder.load_file('camera.kv')
Builder.load_file('input.kv')

#global variables
amount = ''
tip = ''
total = ''
split= ''

class CameraScreen(Screen):
    pass

class DisplayScreen(Screen):
    def displayfill(self):
        input1 = self.manager.get_screen("input_screen")
        amount = input1.ids.orgamount.text
        tip_3 = input1.ids.orgtip.text
        self.finalamount.ids.text = "Tip: {tip}  Tip %: {tip_3}  Total: {total}"



class InputScreen(Screen):
    def calculations(self):
        org_amount = self.ids.orgamount.text
        org_tip = int(self.ids.orgtip.text)
        org_split = int(self.ids.split1.text)

        tip1 = org_tip/100
        tip = round(tip1*float(org_amount), 2)
        total = round(tip + float(org_amount), 2)
        total_str = str(int(total))
        total_x = total_str[-1]

        if org_split == 0:
            split = org_split
        else:
            split = round(total/org_split, 2)




class SettingScreen(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenSwitch(ScreenManager):
    pass

class tipBotApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "tibBot                            version: 1"
        return ScreenSwitch()

    def capture(self, *args):
        cam = self.root.ids.camera
        timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        cam.export_to_png("Image.png")




tipBotApp().run()
```

camera.kv

```
<CameraScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Camera:
            id: camera

    BoxLayout:
        cols: 2
        rows: 1
        Button:
            id: camerainput
            text: "CAPTURE"
            on_press: app.capture
        Button:
            id: cameramanual
            text: "MANUAL ENTRY"
            pos: dp(600), dp(400)
            on_press: app.root.current = "input_screen"
```

input.kv

```
<InputScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "PLEASE ENTER INFORMATION"
            bold: True
            font_size: '35sp'


        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 6
            Label:
                text: "Enter Original Amount of Bill:"
                bold: True
                font_size: '30sp'
            TextInput:
                id: orgamount
                hint_text: 'Enter number w/ 2 decimal places'
                hint_text_color: 'gray'
                multiline: False
                font_size: '30sp'

            Label:
                text: 'Enter tip amount as whole number:'
                bold: True
                font_size: '30sp'
            TextInput:
                id: orgtip
                hint_text_color: 'gray'
                hint_text: 'Enter a whole number'
                multiline: False
                font_size: '30sp'

            Label:
                text: 'Number splitting bill:'
                bold: True
                font_size: '30sp'
            TextInput:
                id: split1
                hint_text: 'Enter # splitting bill'
                hint_text_color: 'gray'
                font_size: '30sp'
                multiline: False

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            Button:
                id: inputsubmit
                text: 'SUBMIT'
                on_press: root.calculations()
                on_press: app.root.current = "display_screen"

            Button:
                id: inputreset
                text: 'RESET'
            Button:
                id: inputsetting
                text: 'SETTINGS'
```

tipBot.kv

```
<ScreenSwitch>:
    CameraScreen:
        name: 'camera_screen'
        id: camera_screen
    DisplayScreen:
        name: 'display_screen'
        id: display_screen
    InputScreen:
        name: 'input_screen'
        id: input_screen
    SettingScreen:
        name: 'setting_screen'
        id: setting_screen
```

display.kv

```
<DisplayScreen>:
    Gridlayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Original Amount Tip Information"
            bold: True
            font_size: '40sp'
        TextInput:
            id: finalamount
            bold: True
            font_size: '40sp'

        Label:
            text: "Rounded to Nearest Dollar"
            bold: True
            font_size: '40sp'
        TextInput:
            id: onedollaramount
            bold: True
            font_size: '40sp'
```

Comment: If you have several problems, try to identify them and post (minimal reproducible one) separately. Otherwise someone may just overlook it seeing the excess amount.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually accessing the `global` variables. If you create a variable with the same name as a global variable in a method, that variable will be a local variable that hides the `global` variable. For example, in your `displayfill()` method, there is a local variable named `amount` that is not related to the `global` variable with the same name. The fix is to add the line:

```
global amount
```

at the start of the `displayfill()` method.